# Инструкция COPY в Dockerfile vs. кэш у docker build

Tags: docker

Я [читал](https://sentinelstand.com/article/composer-install-in-dockerfile-without-breaking-cache), что у `docker` проблемы с рекурсивным копированием файлов через `COPY . ./`. Т.е. `docker` может посчитать, что файлы не изменились, и использовать последующие слои из кэша для построения образа.

В статьях, где пишется про такие проблемы приводится и решение:

```
COPY composer.json ./
COPY composer.lock ./
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader
COPY . ./
RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize && composer run-scripts post-install-cmd
```

Т.е. сначала копируем файлы менеджера пакетов, которые могут поменяться, затем загружаем все зависимости, потом копируем вообще всё, а затем выполняем некоторые процедуры деплоя

У себя в локальном окружении я не смог воспроизвести проблему, но всё равно перестраховался. И из-за этого мой образ, наверное, в полтора-два раза больше занимает, чем если бы я не перестраховывался. И у меня сложилось впечатление, что я борюсь с ветряными мельницами.

Вопрос такой: действительно ли у `docker` есть проблема с копированием и кэшем? Быть в командной строке использовать `docker build --no-cache=true` и тогда можно будет использовать `COPY . ./` не опасаясь проблем?

Comment: вы образы с какой целью создаете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman чтобы положить их в container registry, а затем запускать этот образ через `docker-compose.yml` на удалённом сервере

Comment: это для разработки? или для prod серверов?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman образы используются для staging/production, `docker build` запускается автоматически, разработка ведётся локально (без `docker build`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблем с кэшем нет.

В момент выполнения **COPY** и/или **ADD** считаются контрольные суммы всех файлов и потом ищутся возможные "попадания" кэша. Если ничего не нашлось, то строится новый слой.

В момент выполнения **RUN** проверяется только сама команда и поэтому могут быть ложные "попадания".

Вот такая последовательность

```
COPY composer.json ./
COPY composer.lock ./
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader
```

Помогает докеру не делать установку зависимостей каждый раз, а только когда зависимости поменяются, то есть помогает кешу "попадать". Так как если **composer.json** и/или **composer.lock** поменяются, то произойдет сброс кэша. Если поставить **RUN** до **COPY**, то зависимости не будут обновляться.

Comment: Да! Это значит у меня каша в голове была. Теперь всё встало на свои места! Проблема не в том, что кэшируется или нет, а то в том, что оно должно попадать в кэш много раз. Спасибо =)

Comment: @АндрейМиндубаев ещё одна вещь - образы для prod и Для разработки обычно отличаются. Но это тема для отдельного обсуждения.

Comment: соглашусь, у нас так и есть

Comment: Я понял почему у меня вообще возник такой вопрос!!1 В самом самом начале я создавал образы `docker` внутри контейнера c `docker:dind`. И там не получалось использовать кэш докера вообще. Поэтому я перед `composer install` добавял в образ кэш composer-а. Оно работало быстрее и не скачивало пакеты из интернета каждый раз. А недавно я начал создавать образы внутри контейнера с `docker:latest` но с проброшенным с хоста `/var/run/docker.sock`, а система с кэшем composer - осталась. Сейчас же я всё исправил, сделал как в вашем ответе, всё заработало гораздо быстрее! =) Спасибо